# Assign 0 Record found instead of Undefined variable: count

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am bit new to Codeigniter. 
When I use following code It's count the record and prompt like Ex : **"2 Records Founds "**

```
<td><?php echo $i++; $count=$i-1; ?></td>

<h4 class="notice"><?php  echo $count; ?> Records Found</h4>
```

But when no results is passing for the array I want to show **0 Records found** instead of this Undefined variable: count

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: count

Comment: Where did you initialized your variable ... ?

Comment: `<?php if (isset($records) && $records != "No records found") : $i = 1 : ; foreach ($records as $row) :?>`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple, you just need to initialise `$count = 0;` before the part of the code that currently gets it.

From your sample code, you need to change this:

```
<?php if (isset($records) && $records != "No records found") : $i = 1; foreach ($records as $row) :?>
```

To this:

```
<?php $count = 0; if (isset($records) && $records != "No records found") : $i = 1; foreach ($records as $row) :?>
```

Simples.

Comment: `<?php if (isset($records) && $records != "No records found") : $i = 1 : ; foreach ($records as $row) :?>`

Comment: @MinuMunasinghe are you sure that's a direct copy/paste? `$i = 1 : ;` should cause a parse error immediately.

Comment: sorry it should be `: $i = 1; `